# Java - Como utilizar los textos que fueron el resultado de un if else

Tags: java, desarrollo

Buenas noches amigos espero esten muy bien, acudo a su valiosa sabiduria con el siguiente problema el cual **no logre resolver el ultimo punto**

> **Ejercicio:**
> Realizar un programa en Java que tome dos lecturas por teclado. En una lectura, el usuario deberá > escribir su género
> (masculino o femenino) y en la siguiente lectura, su edad.
>
> En base a los datos registrados, el programa deberá determinar que si
> la edad es mayor o igual a 18, se enviará un mensaje por pantalla que
> diga: "Eres mayor de edad", de lo contrario, se dirá: "Eres menor de
> edad".
>
> También, si el usuario escribe "masculino", se debe desplegar por
> pantalla un mensaje que diga: "Eres un hombre", si escribe "femenino",
> desplegara "Eres una mujer".
>
> **Al final, dependiendo los datos que el usuario ingrese, deberá
> imprimirse una leyenda similar a la siguiente: *Hola, eres un hombre de
> 18 años. Eres mayor de edad.***

**Puntualmente la parte que no pude realizar es deberá imprimirse una leyenda similar a la siguiente: Hola, eres un hombre de 18 años. Eres mayor de edad. porque no se si debo crear otra clase o como proceder.**

Comparto el codigo que llevo en caso de estar cometiendo equivocaciones agradezco sus feedback dado que ando iniciando en el mundillo del desarrollo y le di como dos horas y realmente no pude, el profesor me acepto el ejercicio como esta sin embargo no me siento tranquilo si no lo soluciono completo quiero aprender muy bien por eso agradezco sus colaboraciones.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Hawk
 */
public class EdadGenero {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hola cual es tu genero?");
        String genero = sc.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Cual es tu edad");
        int edad = sc.nextInt();
        
        if (edad >= 18) {
        System.out.println("Eres mayor de edad");
        }
        
        else if (edad <= 0){
        System.out.println("La edad ingresada es incorrecta");
        }
        
        else {
        System.out.println("Eres menor de edad");
        }
        
        if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase("masculino")){
        System.out.println("Eres un Hombre");
        }
        
        else if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase("femenino")){
        System.out.println("Eres una Mujer");
        }
        
        else {
        System.out.println("El genero ingresado es incorrecto");
        }
    }
}
```

Cordial saludo para todos

**Bendiciones**

Comment: Es verdad que puedes hacerlo así como planteas. Se llama programación imperativa. Muchos if else. Pero aprovecha que es JAVA. Crea una súper clase persona, crea subclases hombre y mujer. Crea un polimorfismo. Empieza por un esquema. Vamos campeón tu puedes

Comment: ya intentaste usar `System.out.printf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay soluciones mas optimizadas para esto, pero para que entiendas de acuerdo lo elaborado al nivel de tu pregunta lo hice de esta forma. Espero que sirva

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Edad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        String genero = null;
        String esMayor = null;

        out.printf("Hola cual es tu genero?");
        String generoIn = sc.nextLine();
        out.println("Cual es tu edad");
        int edadIn = sc.nextInt();


        if (edadIn >= 0 && edadIn <= 17) {
            esMayor = "menor";
        }else if (edadIn >= 18){
            esMayor = "mayor";
        }else {
            out.println("La edad ingresada es incorrecta");
            return;
        }

        if (generoIn.equalsIgnoreCase("masculino")){
            genero = "un hombre";
        }else if (generoIn.equalsIgnoreCase("femenino")){
            genero = "una mujer";
        }else {
            out.println("El genero ingresado es incorrecto");
            return;
        }

        System.out.printf("Hola, eres %s de %d años. Eres %s de edad.", genero, edadIn, esMayor);

    }

}
```